# onmouseover opacity change isn't working

Tags: css, opacity

Any idea why this isn't working? The default style in CSS is opacity = 0. Not only does the opacity not change in the div I want to appear, but when the mouse goes over the link it doesn't even show it as being a link. (it works well when I use "visibility" instead of the opacity property, but it causes blinking due to the action triggering the "onmouseout" event)

```
<a href="#" onMouseOver=" document.getElementById('pop_up1').style.opacity = 1" onMouseOut="document.getElementById('pop_up1').style.opacity = 0">
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#pop_up1 {
    opacity: 0;
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Oh wait, I think I see the problem. Even though the #pop_up1 div is invisible it is still over all the links and thus nothing is registered by the mouse at all. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: a Demo of the actual problem would be useful...at the moment we don't have enough code to go on.

Comment: Your code works well enough as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/zrhrkpm9/ so basically the mistake is anywhere else... (is your `a`tag closed?)

Comment: Okay, the best solution I found was to have the visibility change to 1 onmouseover, but instead of using "onmouseout", put the visibility change back to 0 on the actual #pop_up1 div (using onclick instead).

This makes more sense!

Answer (score 1):

> "Oh wait, I think I see the problem. Even though the #pop_up1 div is
>   invisible it is still over all the links and thus nothing is
>   registered by the mouse at all. Is there a way to solve this problem?"

-- use `display:none` instead of opacity to hide it, like

```
#pop_up1 {
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
}
```